# Several page.count in my Microsoft Graph Subscription

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, outlook, office365

i'm subscribed to an email resource to get new emails notifications, this is what is happening.
When i get a message i got a notification inside that notification and has page.count in this case is one. BUT if receive two emails at the same time i will get two notifications with page.count=2 so my question is;
If i get one email, Shouldn't I receive inside that notification one email and in the other notification the other email so in every notification the page count is always 1?? I'd appreciate your answers:) greetings.

Comment: Can you mark below response as an answer if it helped you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior, I am not sure which code you are using, but you should use [@odata.deltaLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msgraph-changenotifications-trackchanges/7-exercise-track-changes) OR [@odata.nextLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to have controlled behavior of what you want to read.

Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: in this case, count is the number of new emails that a get in my inbox. No the total of emails i have in my inbox

Comment: Does it answer your question?

Comment: Can you describe your issue more? Which SDK you are using?

Comment: Look, for example if i receive one message in my email i will get one notification, the content(page of that notification) will have that email and its properties inside, but, if i get 2 emails at the same time, i get the two notifications, but inside those notifications(the page) has the two emails, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msgraph-changenotifications-trackchanges/ this is the tutorial i'm following

Comment: Sure, let me look at it and get back to you. Btw, what is the issue there again?

Comment: the issue is that i need to make sure if this is normal behaviour, i need to make like a history and if that's the case I'll get repeated information, otherwise i will need to make a lot of changes in my app jaj

Comment: Dos this answer help you?

Comment: Hi sorry, i saw that every notification brings the email id(ResourceData) the problem is in this part of the code from the tutorial: lastPage.InitializeNextPageRequest(graphClient, deltaLink.ToString());
                page = await lastPage.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();                                                 As there are two new messages the nextPage will contain those two messages, so in the two email notification example above it will do the same process  but as nexPage contains two new messages. Hope someone with the same doubt helps it. Greetings and thanks singhh-msft:)